# Parsing error with variable declared outside of function

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple class that will create a simple log file for my site. For some reason, when I have variable file_path outside of the function, I get this error...

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''
```

With this code..

```
class Logger {

public $file_path = SITE_ROOT.DS.'logs'.DS.'log.txt';

public static function log_action ($message="") {
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {
        file_put_contents($file_path, $message, FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        return "could not write to log file";
    }
}
```

However when the variable is within the function, this error doesn't come. Why is this?

```
public static function log_action ($action, $message="") {
    $file_path = SITE_ROOT.DS.'logs'.DS.'log.txt';
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {
        file_put_contents($file_path, $message, FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        return "could not write to log file";
    }
```

Comment: You can't use functions, operators such as concatenation, etc when defining class properties. If you want to assign a value that uses concatenation, then do so within your class constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside classes, the PHP code you can run *outside* methods is limited:

> Class member [...] are
> defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
> followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may
> include an initialization, but this **initialization must be a constant
> value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
> must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated**.

From [Properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Thus this is not valid:

```
public $file_path = SITE_ROOT.DS.'logs'.DS.'log.txt';
```

Comment: Thanks! So how would I reuse this file path when I want to use for other functions within the class?

Comment: It'd normally be set in the constructor but, since you plan to use it in static methods, that's not an option. You'll need to set it from outside the class (it's a public property after all) or make the static method call another static method to obtain the path.